# Display JSON_Encoded string variable, in HTML, without quotes

Tags: php, html, json

I have the variable `$target` in PHP and I am using `json_encode` in order to convert the PHP variable so that I can display it in HTML:

```
            $js_target = json_encode($target);




            $Content6 = <<<EOD
            
            <div>$js_target</div>
            
EOD;

            $Content6 .="\n";

            return $Content6;
```

This correctly results in the contents of variable `$js_target` being displayed on the webpage.

The issue is that the displayed data has quotes.

How can I ensure that quotes are not displayed when presenting the variable data on the webpage?

Comment: It's not JSON without the quotes.  Try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PHP variable is an array, you can convert it to a string and then remove the quotes with the following:

```
$js_target = str_replace('"', '', json_encode($target));
```